# DIV Overflow problem

Tags: html, css

I have a website here: [bgflirt.com](http://bgflirt.com/events/calendar/). The problem is that the div containing the flash and the other content (on the right) has to be able to overflow the parent element. But the parent element should have overflow hidden. The result is that the div on the right is cut whenever the div in the middle has no more content to display. How do I let the right div overflow the parent one ? So I can see the entire menu on the right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is just adding a min-height to #content:

```
#content {
min-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the items (or number of items) in the "right div" do not change frequently, the easiest fix is to add this rule to `#content` :

```
min-height: 440px;
```

I picked `440px` because that is the height of the "right div" according to Firebug.

Also, I feel obliged to point out that the HTML/CSS structure of your site is not very good. You should consider doing something about it, or you could continue to have problems making simple changes to the layout of your site.